# How can I programmatically hide app icon after the installation in android , then access thru secret code like *#*#numbers*#*#?

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and I want my app to hide application icon after installation. I will use the code for my thesis. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to make a receiver like this..

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (LAUNCHER_NUMBER.equals("**11**")) {
            PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class);
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        } else if (LAUNCHER_NUMBER.equals("**22**")) {

            ComponentName componentToEnable = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentToEnable, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        }
    }
}
```

Add this Permission to manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Register it to manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Enjoy Coding...

Comment: and then no need to do anything on main activity class... just run it... go to your dialer and type ** **11** ** to hide the app icon and ** **22** ** to unhide it...

Comment: any Android 10 solution ? Any permission we need to do it in Android 10 ?